# Display the state of Grub's recordfail-variable in the boot-menu

Tags: grub2

Grub uses a variable named `recordfail`. The value of this variable affects the behaviour of the Grub-menu, it has influence on the boot-menu timeout and may lead to display the boot-menu even if one has set the boot-menu to be hidden.

For the purpose of troubleshooting, I'd like to see the value of the `recordfail`-variable in the boot-menu. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `recordfail` is either unset or set to `1`. The variable is stored in `/boot/grub/grub/env`.
To see the state of this variable in the boot-menu, we can add custom menu-entries, depending on the state of the variable.

I added the following lines to `/etc/grub.d/40.custom`:

```
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
    menuentry 'Found recordfail=1, reset' {unset recordfail; save_env recordfail; reboot}
else
    menuentry 'recordfail was not set' {reboot}
fi
```

Make the file executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/40.custom
```

and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

A menu-entry depending on `recordfail` will be added to Grub's boot menu:

- If `recordfail` is set to `1`,the menu-entry `Found recordfail=1, reset` will be added to the boot-menu, selecting this entry will unset the recordfail-variable, save it in `/boot/grub/grubenv` and then reboot.
- If `recordfail` is not set, the menu-entry `recordfail was not set` will be added to the boot-menu, selecting it will just reboot.

Note that this will not work if `/boot` resides in a btrfs-filesystem or in LVM. In this case, Grub's `recordfail`-function will be disabled.